# .NET / Entity Framework - System.Data.UpdateException not precise enough?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, updateexception

i got thrown into a small .NET migration project that is using the Entity Framework and MS SQL Server 2005. when persisting data that is not working with db schema (e.g. a string is too long), I am getting an exception System.Data.UpdateException that says "String or binary data would be truncated". But there is no information to which field it relates. does someone has a clue how to get this?

thx

here the stacktrace:

```
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager entityCache)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges()
   at HAM.Inventory.Data.Repository.DocumentRepository.Save(Document document) in D:\ludewigg\Documents\Projects\HAM\src\VBS-HAM-Inventory\Main\HAM.Inventory.Data\Repository\DocumentRepository.cs:line 177
   at HAM.Inventory.Business.Managers.DocumentManager.Save(Document document) in D:\ludewigg\Documents\Projects\HAM\src\VBS-HAM-Inventory\Main\HAM.Inventory.Business\Managers\DocumentManager.cs:line 75
   at HAM.Inventory.MigrationClient.Common.Migration.SaveItem(ItemBase item) in D:\ludewigg\Documents\Projects\HAM\src\VBS-HAM-Inventory\Main\HAM.Inventory.MigrationClient\Common\Migration.cs:line 143
   at HAM.Inventory.MigrationClient.Common.Migration.SaveAndClearItems(List`1 items) in D:\ludewigg\Documents\Projects\HAM\src\VBS-HAM-Inventory\Main\HAM.Inventory.MigrationClient\Common\Migration.cs:line 76
```

and the inner exception:

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
```

Comment: just added to post, but can't see anything

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `StateEntries` property. It should have all the failing objects.

Comment: the object I know, but which field?

Comment: @user524906: Well you would have to look for that, and make sure there are no strings that are too long.

Comment: @user524906: Attach the SQL profiler, that should be quite easy to spot. Or turn on the datacontext's log.

Comment: haven't tried yet the datacontext log, but playing around with the profiler. i copied the query from there to SSMS in order to see the resulting error. but SSMS never finishs executing the query!! weird, it seems SSMS cant handle "exec sp_executesql" statements...

Comment: do i have to rewrite the query? the sql statement is "exec sp_executesql N'insert..., N'@0 uniqueidentifier,@1,..."

Comment: @user524906: You need to validate your data, and make sure the offending string is not too long.

Comment: well, thanks a lot so far! you are right, validation would be the best approach. anyway, for this case i was just looking for a quick and simple way to determine the field/column that raises the exception.